# Why does the div on the right side enable the horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: css, html, css-position

**What I want to achieve**

- Two overlapping background divs behind my centered text content.

  - One at the bottom left side of the text content div.
  - One at the top right side of the text content div.
  - Both should be a little bit behind the text content.
  - Both should be attached to the text div.
- The horizontal scrollbar should be visible only if the window's width is less than `div.text`'s width.
- So additionally, If the two background divs go outside the visible area, they should not enable the horizontal scrollbar.

**What I already have**

- See this [simple JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UBdp3/6/). Tested in Chrome 25 and FireFox 19.

**Problems**

Now, if I reduce the window width so that the blue and red boxes get outside the visible area, the horizontal scrollbar is displayed. However, if I set `display: none;` on `div.right`, the scrollbar is not displayed.

How do I get the desired functionality with `div.right` too, so that if the blue and red boxes are cut off by the window frame, the horizontal scrollbar stays hidden? Is there a nice, cross-browser compatible solution for this?

**EDIT**

On my actual site, the red and blue boxes will contain an image, so I'm also considering solutions like cutting the bg-images in half, and setting the smaller parts as a `background-image` for the content div.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, can you structure your question perhaps with some bullets to point out the actual requirements? Also I have a strong feeling this should be possible just with pure CSS but that's merely a gut feeling based on what I see in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @Bazzz edited my question as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `CSS` only, by using `CSS3 Calc` and setting the body to `position: relative`.

Live DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/AMC93/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, etc</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.right {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    right: calc(50% - 230px);
}
.left {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -2;
    left: calc(50% - 230px);
    bottom: 0;
}
.text {
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 800;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For me, this only works in Chrome. Is there a way to do this in cross-browser way? +1 for letting me know of CSS calc!

Comment: firefox requires the vendor prefix `-moz-calc`

Comment: @david Not necessarily, not anymore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F-moz-calc#Browser_compatibility (since Firefox 16)

Comment: @DanielSzalay only in Chrome ? I fiddled it in Firefox 19... :|

Comment: Right, sorry it was false. Checked again and it works in FF19.

Comment: By the way as @david suggested, you should (always) include (any) vendor specific property aside the standard one, to make it works in old browsers too ;)

Comment: Based on [this](http://caniuse.com/calc), your statement is not entirely true. What if I want the same functionality for IE8?

Comment: When targeting ALL browsers, you need to decide the way to go. You can use additional CSS rules (defined before the rules that won't be read by old browsers), additional javascript, or go for a little different site rendering on old browser, while preserving the navigability. Based on your choice, you should start finding the solution... welcome to the jungle

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following and I hope it addresses your problem

```
$('.left').css('left', 0);
$('.right').css('right', 0);
```

Try this solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see how this would do anything like the desired functionality.